# dynamically added element is not wired on jquery event

Tags: javascript, jquery

on dom ready I have wired event

```
$('.someClass').on('input', function (e) {
   //  do something
});
```

on same I'm injecting html elements with where I add .someClass to include that field for same event

```
var cssClass = "form-control";
if (myProperty == true) {
     cssClass = "form-control someClass";
}
('#myTable tr:last').after(
   '<tr>'+
   '<td><input class=' + cssClass + ' type="text"'</td></tr>'+
   '</tr>'
);
```

but I'm getting rendered inside firebug as

```
<input class="form-control someClass" type="text"</td someClass="">
```

and this field is not fetched on .someClass event

Comment: Half dupe of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 1):

the solution is to write:

```
$('body').on('input','.someClass', function (e) {
   //  do something
});
```

and fix your code:

```
$('#myTable tr:last').after(
   '<tr>'+
   '<td><input class=' + cssClass + ' type="text"/></td></tr>'
);
```

Comment: He is getting issue at this line of code.
<input class="form-control someClass" type="text"</td someClass="">

Answer (score 0):

Mmm... aren't you missing the quotation mark (") in the input's class?

Furthermore, you are not correctly appending the td and tr closing tags. Try something like this:

```
$('#myTable tr:last').after(
    '<tr>' +
    '<td><input class="' + cssClass + '" type="text" /></td>' + 
    '</tr>'
);
```